# Getting the inverse of a function that uses summation in Java

Tags: java

I have a program with one class, which looks like this.

```
public class Functions {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(summationFunction(1)); //Prints 13
        System.out.println(summationFunction(2)); //Prints 29
        System.out.println(summationFunction(3)); //Prints 48
        System.out.println(summationFunction(4)); //Prints 70
    }

    public static int summationFunction(int input) {
        int summedNumber = 0;
        int i = input;
        while (i > 0) {
            summedNumber += i * 3;
            i--;

        }
        return 10 * input + (summedNumber);
    }


}
```

So, this program will take in a given number and apply this function to it:

[image: The function of my method.]

And this all works well (I have run the class `Functions` and everything prints just as it's supposed to.) BUT, I need to find the inverse of this function, and I need to be able to translate it to code; I do not know how to do this.

I basically need a function that will return values like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(summationFunction(13)); //Prints 1
    System.out.println(summationFunction(29)); //Prints 2
    System.out.println(summationFunction(48)); //Prints 3
    System.out.println(summationFunction(70)); //Prints 4
}
```

which, (as you can tell) is the opposite of the original function.

So to sum everything up, **I need a function that will return the inverse of my original function (`summationFunction`)**, and **I would like to know how I would model this or if there is a quick solution, in code.**

One more thing: I know that I can have the method take an input and search for the most similar output of the original method, but I would like to see if there is a simpler way to do this which does not involve searching, thus giving a quicker output speed. And if you wish you can safely assume that **the input of the inversed function will always be a number which will give an integer output**, like 13, 29, 48, 70, etc...

**By the way,** if you are going to downvote the question, will you at least give a reason somewhere? The comments perhaps? I can not see any reason that this question is eligible for being downvoted, and a reason would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10*x%2B+(sum+3*i,+i%3D1+to+x)) to the rescue !

It tells you that this function can be written as :

```
1/24*(6*x+23)^2-529/24
```

So if you want to solve f(x)=a, you have :

```
x = 1/6*(sqrt(24*a+529)-23)

a = 70
# => x = 4
```

Note : Using Wolfram shouldn't prevent you from finding the answer on your own.

```
sum(something*i) is equal to something*sum(i) because something (3 in this case ) doesn't depend on i.
```

sum(i,i=1..n) is equal to n*(n+1)/2, and it's easy to prove (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number))

```
So your function becomes 10*x+3*x*(x+1)/2
Expanded, it is :
(3 x^2)/2+(23 x)/2
You need to solve (3 x^2)/2+(23 x)/2 = 70, in other words :
(3 x^2)/2+(23 x)/2 - 70 = 0
```

It is a [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation), with a=3/2, b=23/2 and c=-70 or c=-29 or c=....

Comment: Ahh. I have not heard of Wolfram before. Thank you and and @talex both for providing resources and a better description of this!

Answer (score 2):

You sum can be written like this `3*x*(x+1)/2` so you have equation `10*x + 3*x*(x+1)/2 = y` you need to solve it.

Wolfram alpha tells that result will be `1/6.0 * (-23.0+sqrt(529.0+24.0 * y))`